# Error: Cannot find module 'aws-api-gateway-client'

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to execute nodejs code to invoke AWS API using aws-api-gateway-client module. Code workes perfectly in my laptop however when deployed to TEST server which has latest nodejs and aws npm module installed.

```
 var apigClientFactory = require('aws-api-gateway-client')
```

Path Npm modules are installed:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules
```

Output

```
''' internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'aws-api-gateway-client'
Require stack:
- C:\Myfolder\agent\scripts\NodeJSAWSConnector\APINetworks.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ServiceNow\foggydev\agent\scripts\NodeJSAWSConnector\APINetworks.js:8:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\MyFolder\\agent\\scripts\\NodeJSAWSConnector\\APINetworks.js'
  ]
}
'''
```

Please advise on the above issue.

Update 2:

`package.json` file has entry

```
 "dependencies": {
        "JSONStream": "^1.3.5",
        "abbrev": "~1.1.1",
        "ansicolors": "~0.3.2",
        "ansistyles": "~0.1.3",
        "aproba": "^2.0.0",
        "archy": "~1.0.0",
        "aws-api-gateway-client": "^0.3.3",
        "aws-sdk": "^2.656.0",
        "bin-links": "^1.1.7",
        "bluebird": "^3.5.5",
        "byte-size": "^5.0.1",
        "cacache": "^12.0.3",
        "call-limit": "^1.1.1",
        "chownr": "^1.1.4",
        "ci-info": "^2.0.0",
        "cli-columns": "^3.1.2",
        "cli-table3": "^0.5.1",
```

Also, `aws-api-gateway-client` is installed at `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is in `C:\ServiceNow\foggydev\agent\scripts\NodeJSAWSConnector\APINetworks.js`

`node_modules` are in: `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules`

Seems like You've installed `aws-api-gateway-client` globally (since You're saying that `node_modules` folder is in different place)

Steps to check and solve:

1) check `package.json` file if it exists in dependencies,

2) make sure in Your test server `aws-api-gateway-client` exists in `node_modules` folder,

3) do `npm i --save aws-api-gateway-client` to install it in `node_modules` folder relative to Your project, which will also add that module to dependencies in `package.json`

4) deploy to test server again with updated `packge.json`

Comment: Thanks for response: I have checked 'aws-api-gateway-client' exists in node_module folder.

Comment: @KiranPatil then it mean You're running script not from package.json level, add in package.json `"scripts": {"api-networks": "node path/to/APINetworks.js"}` and then run as: `npm run api-networks`

Comment: I have removed nodejs and all packages and installed nodejs back to `C:/Program Files\nodeks` and I cannot install aws-api npm package in `C:\ServiceNow\foggydev\agent\scripts\NodeJSAWSConnector\APINetworks.js` as this is auto generated folder. Now, please help me install npm packages ar right path and other configuration needed to run the projects from `C:\ServiceNow\foggydev\agent\scripts\NodeJSAWSConnector\APINetworks.js`

Comment: in which folder package.json is?

Comment: Here is `package.json` file `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\package.json`

Comment: that's the problem! what are You doing in global node_modules folder? You don't know how nodejs AMD works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212302/discussion-between-num8er-and-kiran-patil).

Comment: Thank you so much for you help. Issue is resolved now. I created a directory `node_modules` in `C:\ServiceNow\foggydev\agent` and installed `aws-gateway` packages here and `package.json` file. API will execute the code using powershell from this location `C:\ServiceNow\foggydev\agent`